# html_attr "href" does not extract link

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to download the file that is in the tab "Dossier" with the text "Modul 4" here:

https://www.g-ba.de/bewertungsverfahren/nutzenbewertung/5/#dossier

First I want to get the link.
My code for that is the following:

```
"https://www.g-ba.de/bewertungsverfahren/nutzenbewertung/5/#dossier" %>% 
    read_html %>% 
    html_nodes(".gba-download__text") %>% 
    .[[4]] %>% 
    html_attr("href")
```

(I know the piece `.[[4]]` is not really good, this is not my full code.)
This leads to `NA` and I don't understand why.
Similar questions couldn't help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to get to a specific node if you use `xpath` :

```r
library(rvest)

"https://www.g-ba.de/bewertungsverfahren/nutzenbewertung/5/#dossier" %>% 
    read_html %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'Modul 4')]/..") %>% 
    .[[1]] %>% 
    html_attr("href")

#> [1] "/downloads/92-975-67/2011-12-05_Modul4A_Apixaban.pdf"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a really great solution! Could you explain this a little bit? Didn't know something like `contains(text()`...  Do you have a keyword that I can learn this? And why do I get the link twice if I don't use `.[[1]]`?

Comment: @TobiSonne xpath is a grammar for navigating through xml and html. It is quite separate from R, but is implemented in `xml2` and `rvest`. You can get an introduction [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp), but in this case the path says "find any span tag whose text contains "Modul 4" then go to its parent node". The reason for the `.[[1]]` is the same as yours - it turns out there were 2 identical nodes, but I only wanted one of them. I don't know why there are two. The problem with web scraping is that html frequently changes and its structure doesn't always make sense!

Answer (score 4):

Allan already left a concise answer. But let me leave another way. If you check the page source, you can see that the target is in `.gba-download-list`. (There are actually two of them.) So get that part and walk down to `href` part. Once you get urls, you can use `grep()` to identify a link containing `Modul4`. I used `unique()` in the end to remove a dupe.

```
read_html("https://www.g-ba.de/bewertungsverfahren/nutzenbewertung/5/#dossier") %>% 
  html_nodes(".gba-download-list") %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  grep(pattern = "Modul4", value = TRUE) %>% 
  unique()

[1] "/downloads/92-975-67/2011-12-05_Modul4A_Apixaban.pdf"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, great answer, too!

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution now and want to share it:

```
"https://www.g-ba.de/bewertungsverfahren/nutzenbewertung/5/#dossier" %>% 
    read_html %>% 
    html_nodes("a.download-helper") %>% 
    html_attr("href") %>% 
    .[str_detect(., "Modul4")] %>% 
    unique
```

Answer (score 1):

It is faster to use a css selector with contains operator to target the href by substring. In addition, only a single node match needs to be returned

```
library(rvest)

 url <- "https://www.g-ba.de/bewertungsverfahren/nutzenbewertung/5/#dossier"
 link <-  read_html(url) %>% 
    html_node("[href*='Modul4']") %>% 
    html_attr("href") %>% url_absolute(url)
```